# Hyper-v Manager, 1 External Switch, 2 Private switch on cento7 vm, cannot ping internet

Tags: hyper-v, centos7

I'm using hyper-v manager on windows 10 creators update

I've set up 1 external switch and 2 private switches which are connected to a vm through the network Adapter. In the vm which is Centos7 I can see that eth0 is on the External adapter, and eth1 on the correct private network adapter and eth2 which is also on the correct private network adapter. We'll call this vm with 3 adapters.

there I can ping from the vm this is created on to any other vm on the switches, the issue I'm having is that I can't ping anywhere on the internet, there appears to be no outbound connectivity. As well as ping, I've tried wget, links and yum - no connection.

I have a second VM  on the External switch which can ping to external locations on the internet as well as ping the other VM in the External switch and the host.

If I remove the private switches from the VM with 3 adapters reducing it to just one external switch adapter, then I get outbound connectivity back and am able to ping external locations.

I've tried ping -I eth0  then all three adapters are in place to ensure that I'm routing though the right interface, but again destination unreachable.

I've stopped firewalld amd iptables on the VM with 3 adapters.

I'd like some guidance as to what I should be doing to get the external adapter working as I'd expect which is communicating to the internet.

so far I've done a CentOS minimal install did an yum update and upgrade, installed nano, links, wget and firewalld. The configured eth0, eth1, & eth2, then shutdown and attached the 2 private switched and started up. eth0 is dcph, eth1 & 2 are both static with an addigned ip, No further configuration or installation other than that.

So what should I do to get eth0 on the external switch communicating with the internet.

Comment: fixed it. added two new zones to firewalld, then in the ifcfg-eth1 & ifcfg-eth2 added the appropriate zones. this removed the other interfaces from the public default zone, allowing eth0 to be outbound.